# Composer PSR-4 for php file

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4

In my project I have a folder `lib\custom`  which contains `Web` folder and `functions.php` file. In my `functions.php` I have some functions which I need to use in another classes and in this file on the first line I have a defined namespace  look like this

```
<?php
namespace Custom;

function abc(){....}
```

And in Web folder I have some classes with namespace `Custom\Web`;

In my `composer.json` file I have defined namespace look like this

```
"Custom\\":"lib/custom/"
```

So , now I am using the  `abc()`  look like this

```
use Custom;
$abc = Custom\abc("abc")
```

but as a response I am getting

> Call to undefined function Custom\abc()

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: if you say `use Custom` you don't need to use it again so `$abc = abc("abc"); ` should work

Comment: I have already tried but not working

Comment: have you tried `Custom::abc()`?

Comment: why???? Do you think its will work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) describes a specification for autoloading classes from file paths. It doesn't cover loading functions from files.

Use [the `files` autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) to load a file with functions on each request automatically. This will make your function available as long as you included the autoloader:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["lib/custom/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

Since your functions are namespaced you'll need to import them with the `use` statement or use the fully qualified name.

If your `Web` folder contains PSR-4 compatible classes, load them as before with the PSR-4 autoloader (you can define multiple autoloaders in your `composer.json`).

Comment: how can I load them as before with psr-4 autoloader?

Comment: As I said you CANNOT load functions with the psr-4 autoloader. It's only for class autoloading. Use psr-4 to load your classes and use the files autoloader as I shown to load functions.